# Not compressing javascript file

Tags: javascript, spring, maven, spring-mvc

**EDIT:** Thanks khmarbaise for your reply.I was not checking in my target folder...Now its working some what better...But the thing is it is not compressing some white spaces.Below is the output im getting after compressing with a single file.

Ext.onReady(function(){new Ext.Window({title:"Hello",width:300,height:500,items:getItems()}).show()
});

function getItems(){var a=new Ext.Panel({title:"I am Item Panel"});
return a
};

After the semicolon,its not compressing the white spaces.....

---

Below is the code which I am using to compress my JS files. I am able to copy my all js files in to a single file. But not able to compress that. Please help me...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>          
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>        
    <configuration>
        <removeIncluded>false</removeIncluded>
        <jswarn>false</jswarn>
        <aggregations>
            <aggregation>
                <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
                <removeIncluded>false</removeIncluded>
                <inputDir>src/main/webapp/resources/js</inputDir>
                <includes>
                    <include>D:/TestWorkSpace/myProject/src/main/webapp/resources/js/panel.js</include>
                </includes>
                <output>src/main/webapp/resources/js/min.js</output>
            </aggregation>
        </aggregations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use hard coded paths like d:/ etc. better use a thing like ${project.basedir} instead.

You shouldn't put modified code back to the src/ area. The output tag seemed to be not existing based on the documentation but in contradiction a tag outputDirectory exist which point to the target folder by default. I would suggest first to try without configuring the output tag.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise for your reply.I was not checking in my target folder...Now its working some what better...But the thing is it is not compressing some white spaces.Below is the output im getting after compressing with a single file.